# Decomposing a relation

Tags: database, relational-database

I have been trying to understand the process of decomposing a relation but with no succes. I have no idea how it works and I can't figure it out. I have an example here if someone could explain me step by step how it works.

```
Consider schema R(A;B;C;D;E) with FDs
F = {AB -> CDE; AC -> BDE; B -> C; C -> B; C -> D; B -> E}.
1. Find all keys of R.

F = {AB -> CDE; AC -> BDE; B -> C; C -> B; C -> D; B -> E}
A+ = A
B+ = BCED
- it is not possible to deduce A from the other attributes -> A belongs to key
AB+ = ABCDE - a candidate key
AC+ = ACBDE - a candidate key
AD+ = AD, 
AE+ = AE
ADE+ = ADE
```

I also don't understand what A+ signifies

Answer (score 0):

What you've posted isn't decomposing a relation. It's finding the candidate keys. The candidate keys here are {AB, AC}.

Finding the keys is the second step in decomposing a relation. The first step is identifying all the dependencies. You're given all the functional dependencies, so you don't have to do that part here.

*A+* means "the closure of the set of attributes A with respect to the set of functional dependencies F"--the set of attributes of F that can be determined by A.

This statement

> it is not possible to deduce A from the other attributes -> A belongs
>   to key

should be

> it is not possible to deduce A from the other attributes -> A belongs
>   to every candidate key

Comment: Why A+ = A and B+ = BCED. I don't understand that.

Comment: The set of attributes "A" determines only the value of "A". You can't determine B, C, D, or E given only A. B->B is trivial; B->C and B->E are given; B->D because B->C and C->D (transitivity). So B->BCDE.